# Naming objects inside of an array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm quite new to JavaScript and programming in general and figured I'd hone my abilities by working on a small project. The idea is that I have a form for information on an event, an input for the name, date, time and a small thumbnail image.

I want each event to be an object inside of an array, so I would have something like:

```
var concerts = {};

for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    window["concert"+i] = new Object();
}
```

and the array would end up being something:

```
var concerts = [concert1, concert2, concert3]
```

and so on.

How could I get this loop to work so that it would take the 3 parameters and create a new object in the array named 'concert'+i? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Take 3 parameters from where?

Answer (score 3):

Concerts must be an array:

```
var concerts = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  concerts[i] = {
    //maybe also giveit a name if you want to:
    name:"concert"+i
  };
}
```

You can access it like this:

```
concerts[0].name="Wacken";//first concert...
```

Note that this:

```
window["concert"+i] = new Object();
```

is very bad style...

Answer (score 0):

First you declare a variable `concerts` of type object. But you want an array. That first line makes your code very confusing.

You have to start with an empty array:

```
var concerts = []; // alternatively: new Array();
```

In the end you'd like to have a structure like this:

```
[
    { /* object 1 */ },
    { /* object 2 */ }
]
```

Now you can run a foor-loop and populate the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    concerts.push({['concert' + i]: {}});
}
```

This will return something like:

```
[
    {'concert0': {}},
    {'concert1': {}},
    // skipped
    {'concert10': {}}
]
```

Later you can populate the objects. This is however not a very nice style. Maybe you should reconsider if it is really necessary to give a name to every object like concert0...10.

Go rather for:

```
var concerts = [
    {
        'name': 'concert0',
        'location': 'somewhere'
    }
    // continue with other objects
];
```

Comment: @Jonasw Thanks for the comment! Array can't be a key in a JavaScript object. This expression however is not an array. The part `['concert' + i]` returns a string - `'concert'` is string and `i` is number. Due to the type coercion in JS the result is a string, returned by the square brackets. Otherwise you couldn't create dynamically the key names in a foor loop.

Comment: oh sorry, ive already forgot that... :/ maybe because i think that dynamic keys are a generally bad idea...

Comment: I think, too, that dynamic keys are a very bad idea. It's what the OP wanted. In JavaScript you can call a value of an object with a dot notation or with square brackets: `var o.name = 'Jonas';` or `var o['name'] = 'Jonas';`. The key in the square brackets can be generated by some operation: `var o['n' + 'am' + 'e'] = 'Jonas';`. In my answer it looks really weird, that is why I suggest in the end to go for another solution.